# Getting email addresses from AD Group MVC

Tags: c#, email, model-view-controller, active-directory

I have the name of my AD Group and I need to return a list of every single email address of the users found inside. I've been looking around trying to find the answer to this but all of the results I've found are aimed at checking an AD Group for a single users email address. Often by using their windows log on username.

However, what I'm wanting to do is to grab every email address inside my target active directory group. As eventually this will be turned into an automated email that needs to be sent to only those individuals within the active directory group.

The project I'm building is making use of MVC 5.

Could someone please point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split this into two steps:

1. Find the group (I assume you just have the name of the group)
2. Get all the members.

**Finding the group**

You *can* use [`GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.findbyidentity), which is arguably easier, but I find that's quite slow (slower the bigger your group is). I prefer to use [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher)/[`DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry) (which is what `GroupPrincipal` uses behind the scenes anyway).

To find the group, your code would look something like this:

```
var groupName = "MyGroup";
var search = new DirectorySearcher() {
    Filter = $"(&(objectClass=group)(cn={groupName}))"
};
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn"); //this is just to prevent it from returning every attribute

//This will throw an exception if the group is not found
var group = ((SearchResult)search.FindOne()).GetDirectoryEntry();
```

If you already have the `distinguishedName` of the group, you can actually skip that and just make a `DirectoryEntry`:

```
var group = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{disginguishedName}");
```

**Getting the members**

I wrote an article on how to do this, with example C# code: [Find all the members of a group](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/11/30/find-all-members-of-group.html)

The example code in that article returns the `DOMAIN\username`, so here is the same method, modified to return a list of email addresses for all the members that have one.

Pass this method the `DirectoryEntry` object we found for the group. Set `recursive` to `true` if you want it to look inside nested groups.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetGroupMemberList(DirectoryEntry group, bool recursive = false) {
    var members = new List<string>();

    group.RefreshCache(new[] { "member" });

    while (true) {
        var memberDns = group.Properties["member"];
        foreach (string member in memberDns) {
            using (var memberDe = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{member.Replace("/", "\\/")}")) {
                memberDe.RefreshCache(new[] { "objectClass", "mail" });

                if (recursive && memberDe.Properties["objectClass"].Contains("group")) {
                    members.AddRange(GetGroupMemberList(memberDe, true));
                } else {
                    var email = memberDe.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) {
                        members.Add(email);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (memberDns.Count == 0) break;

        try {
            group.RefreshCache(new[] {$"member;range={members.Count}-*"});
        } catch (COMException e) {
            if (e.ErrorCode == unchecked((int) 0x80072020)) { //no more results
                break;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
    return members;
}
```

In my article, I also talk about primary groups and Foreign Security Principals, but you don't need to worry about that here since it's not applicable to distribution lists.